# reference webservice from blazor

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor project,
 i need to  ad a webReference to my service 
 I tried to add into "**connected services**" and set the SpaceName as "**LABservice**", but as you can see it gives me some different methods than i have in the service
Now the method **List_UdM** has 4 different method(request,requestbody,response,responseBody), what can i do to call it?
 
I am thinking that "connected services" is the wrong place to add a webService reference

[image]

Comment: "... has 4 different method" - no, you see 4 classes that are used to call an endpoint. Your posted code here is not complete but there is no indication of an error.

Comment: an endpoint,  ok it means the reference to webservice is correct, now do you have any example to call my routin: "list_UdM"?
i dont have a httpwebrequest in Blazor

Comment: Better google/ask for "core 3 and WCF" ...  This shouldn't be Blazor specific. At least I hope you don't try this with WebAssembly.

Comment: Is the service need to be WCF or is a Rest Service also fine?

Comment: rest is fine, thanks